# How to list all the files in android phone by using adb shell?

Tags: android, adb

I just try to write a bash shell for my Android Phone.
When I want list all the files in my Android Phone. I found that the Android shell terminal doesn't support `find` command.
So I just want to know which is the best way to travel the `sdcard` files?

Comment: Note that on a secured Android device, the shell user lacks permission to access many files and list many directories.  On an emulator or engineering device where ADB runs as root, then access to these becomes possible.

Comment: i know it.but i just want to travel the file of the sdcard.i think it couldn't involve the root permission. anyway thanks!

Answer (score 165, accepted):

I might be wrong but "find -name __" works fine for me. (Maybe it's just my phone.)
If you just want to list all files, you can try

```
adb shell ls -R /
```

You probably need the root permission though.

Edit:
As other answers suggest, use `ls` with `grep` like this:

```
adb shell ls -Ral yourDirectory | grep -i yourString
```

eg.

```
adb shell ls -Ral / | grep -i myfile
```

**`-i` is for ignore-case.** and `/` is the root directory.

Comment: Most official-release android devices do not have a `find` command, though those with custom ROMS or other busybox installs may.

Comment: my phone can't get the root permission!i am very sorry for that.if i get the root premission.i will install the busybox.the busybox is very useful tools

Comment: If you only want the sdcard, replace the / in this command with the mountpoint of the sdcard on your system, and then no, you should not need to run it as root.

Comment: If your phone isn't rooted, you can use `adb shell ls /storage` or `adb shell ls -R --color=always /storage` to list from a readable directory.

Answer (score 32):

Open cmd type `adb shell` then press enter.
Type `ls` to view  files list.

Comment: At the DOS prompt, `adb  shell  ls  -R  >  junk` lists all files and puts results into file `junk` which you can then edit via Notepad or whatever and see more than you'd want to, but your files, too!

Answer (score 4):

just to add the full command:

```
adb shell ls -R | grep filename
```

this is actually a pretty fast lookup on Android

Comment: This won't give you the file path, it will only reports if it exists. To get the path I would instruct grep to also report every directory crawled by `ls`, like this: `adb shell ls -laR | grep -E "filename|:$"`

Comment: i like to use `ls -lrta`

Answer (score 3):

This command will show also if the file is hidden 
`adb shell ls -laR | grep filename`

Answer (score 2):

Some Android phones contain Busybox.  Was hard to find.

To see if busybox was around:

```
ls -lR / | grep busybox
```

If you know it's around. You need some read/write space.  Try you flash drive, /sdcard

```
cd /sdcard
ls -lR / >lsoutput.txt
```

upload to your computer.  Upload the file. Get some text editor.  Search for busybox. Will see what directory the file was found in.

```
busybox find /sdcard -iname 'python*'
```

to make busybox easier to access,  you could:

```
cd /sdcard
ln -s /where/ever/busybox/is  busybox
/sdcard/busybox find /sdcard -iname 'python*'
```

Or any other place you want.
R

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with

```
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 34.0.5-10900879
```

In powershell on Win 10, connecting to Pixel 7 / Android 14.
You now have to quote the shell input when piping:

```
adb shell 'ls storage/emulated/0/ | wc'
```