# How and where is Application executable code stored inside a device?

Tags: android

Exactly where inside the data/data/myapp/... is executable code stored? And how is it stored, is it stored as dex code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with

**where**

Connect to your device with adb and the run `pm path here-goes-package-name` command.  Like this:

```
$ adb shell
root@vbox86p:/ # pm path pl.pelotasplus.wptv
package:/data/app/pl.pelotasplus.wptv-1/base.apk
```

This will be a path to .apk on your device.

Some apps, like system apps, are in `/system/app` directory or even `/system/priv-app/`.

```
root@vbox86p:/data # pm path com.google.android.partnersetup
package:/system/priv-app/GooglePartnerSetup/GooglePartnerSetup.apk
```

and answering second part of your question

**how**

They are just .apk files, which are basically a ZIP files.  So if you use `unzip -l` command you will see that the code of your app is kept in .dex file inside above mentioned .apk file

```
root@vbox86p:/data # unzip -l /system/priv-app/GooglePartnerSetup/GooglePartnerSetup.apk | grep .dex   <
276104  08-21-08 17:13   classes.dex
```

Sometimes there can be more than one .dex files -- welcome to the Multi-Dex world!

**cache**

There is also something called dalvik cache, where .dex files are kept for performance reasons.

```
root@vbox86p:/ # ls -al ./data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@pl.pelotasplus.actionafteruninstall-1@base.apk@classes.dex
rw-r--r-- system   all_a102  4690352 2015-05-31 20:17 data@app@pl.pelotasplus.actionafteruninstall-1@base.apk@classes.dex
```

Comment: Thank you so much, so you mean that whenever I run some app, android system unzips that apk file and runs the code every time?

Answer (score 1):

**Where?**

System preset apps are in `/system/app`. Ordinary apps are in `/data/app`. They are stored as `.apk` files which are of type simple ZIP files. `.dex` files also can be accessed by unzipping them. The name of that `.dex` file is `classes.dex`.

**How?**

Whenever you install a new app, Android simplely copy that APK file there. Moreover, in [ART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Runtime), Android also compiles application byte codes to native device codes and save these codes somewhere.

> Unlike Dalvik, ART introduces the use of ahead-of-time (AOT) compilation by compiling entire applications into native machine code upon their installation.

**How can I access there?**

By [ADB](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) (Android Debug Bridge) you can [access Android file system](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16796432/1841194).