# Read .mp3 file from SD card by Xamarin IDE

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mp3, media

Im building mediaplayer for homework and using Xamarin IDE.
MainActivity file in Xamarin have extern .cs. This mean is C# file and I have some trouble with that.
I need get data from SD card. But when i implemented that, i had exception "SetDataSource failed".
Help me.

```
namespace PlayMusic
{
[Activity (Label = "PlayMusic", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it

        Button play                     = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.play_btn);

        //MediaPlayer mp                = MediaPlayer.Create (this, Resource.Raw.anniver);
        MediaPlayer mp                  = new MediaPlayer ();
        var directory                   = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory;
        var fullFileName                = Path.Combine(directory.ToString(), "anniver.mp3");
        mp.SetDataSource (fullFileName);

        play.Click                      += delegate {
            try{
                mp.Start();  
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.StackTrace.ToString();
            }  
        };
    }
}
}
```

The result fullFileName = "/storage/sdcard0/anniver.mp3"
But when IED go to SetDataSource(..) statement, have exception IOException, and failed SetDataSource.
I checked anniver.mp3. That good.

Comment: Somebody help me :'(

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `Xamarin` you can use `c#`'s `Path.Combine` to get to your file like so:

```
var directory = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory;

var fullFileName = Path.Combine(directory.ToString(), "1.mp3");
if (File.Exists(fullFileName))
{
    //proceed
}
```

Comment: have you include using System.IO;

Comment: Result fullFileName = "/storage/sdcard0/anniver.mp3"
Exception: mp.SetData failed.
I dont know where is error in this code

Comment: What is the android version you're targeting?

Comment: my android version 5.0.1.
I'm debuging my app in device lenovo.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the [Android path separator](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Java.IO.File.Separator/) to your mp3 string path:

```
string stringPath  = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path;
mp.SetDataSource (stringPath + Java.IO.File.Separator + "1.mp3");
```

Comment: when i debug my app, stringPath + Java.IO.File.Separator + "1.mp3" = "/storage/sdcard0/1.mp3"
And error SetDataSource failed.
My sdcard name SD card. May It effect on the sofware?

Comment: Use adb to verify your file location : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16796432/how-to-list-all-the-files-in-android-phone-by-using-adb-shell