# Is it possible to search for a file in the Android Emulator file system (within my computer)?

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an Android Emulator I'm trying to use to debug an app I'm developing.

I know in Android Studio they have the Device File Explorer which is helpful but I may not know the exact subfolder where the file I'm looking for lives:

[image: Device File Explorer]

Is there a way either in the Device File Explorer or another tool that can search the file system of an Android Emulator by file name? (My computer's OS is Windows.)

Comment: Android emulator images (and related extended storage files) are single packed files, so the individual files are not visible to the hosting OS. Using the AS Device File Explorer works for accessing "public" files within your emulator instance, but accessing private/sandbox files are only available via root-able emulator images. Otherwise you could copy, within the app itself, the file you want to access, to a public location. i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54126671/access-the-android-special-folder-path-by-using-environment/54127487#54127487

Comment: @SushiHangover That's fine, I'm not necessarily looking for private/sandbox files, but I don't see a **Search** option in the Android Studio **Device File Explorer** to filter down the list of files that it exposes. Is there such an option or an alternative way to do so?

Comment: You can use the Android Debug Bridge (`adb`) for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16796432/how-to-list-all-the-files-in-android-phone-by-using-adb-shell

Comment: @SushiHangover Ah ok thanks. Was looking for something a little more user friendly, but that should help in the interim. Thank you.

Comment: The AS Device File Explorer is using `adb` (as all Android tools do), there are some 3rd party and open source Android utilities that use `adb` for file explorers, etc... but personally I do not use any of them...